# Using Soundclound Custom Player with Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, audio, soundcloud

I have a music blog i am creating, which will be using soundcloud links.  I have a custom player built with soundcloud custom player, (https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player).  Outside of wordpress it works perfectly and loads the next track when one finishes, but on wordpress it doesn't see the next track.  I assume its because it is in the loop and not actually a part of the html?

Please be patient i'm a designer not a coder!  Thanks!!!

at the moment, the code in the sc-player.js is

```
onPlay = function(player, id) {
    var track = getPlayerData(player).tracks[id || 0];
    updateTrackInfo(player, track);
    // cache the references to most updated DOM nodes in the progress bar
    updates = {
      $buffer: $('.sc-buffer', player),
      $played: $('.sc-played', player),
      position:  $('.sc-position', player)[0]
    };
    updatePlayStatus(player, true);
    play(track);
  },
  onPause = function(player) {
    updatePlayStatus(player, false);
    audioEngine.pause();
  },
  onFinish = function() {
    var $player = updates.$played.closest('.sc-player'),
        $nextItem;
    // update the scrubber width
    updates.$played.css('width', '0%');
    // show the position in the track position counter
    updates.position.innerHTML = timecode(0);
    // reset the player state
    updatePlayStatus($player, false);
    // stop the audio
    audioEngine.stop();
    $player.trigger('onPlayerTrackFinish');
  },
  onSeek = function(player, relative) {
    audioEngine.seek(relative);
    $(player).trigger('onPlayerSeek');
  },
  onSkip = function(player) {
    var $player = $(player);
    // continue playing through all players
    log('track finished get the next one');
    $nextItem = $('.sc-trackslist li.active', $player).next('li');
    // try to find the next track in other player
    if(!$nextItem.length){
      $nextItem = $player.nextAll('div.sc-player:first').find('.sc-trackslist li.active');
    }
    $nextItem.click();
  },
```

thanks!!!!

EDIT!!!!!
when the song ends i do get "track finished get the next one" in the log, so that appears to be working, it just isn't getting "the next one!"

Comment: right click and inspect element -> click on console and you should see $ is not defined....replace all instances of `$(**)` with `jQuery(**)` there are 3 or 4 above. Be careful some variables are called $variable above, dont touch these.

Comment: actually not getting that error (i am running jquery)...   the only error i seem to be getting is "Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas width is 0." from the soundcloud api.

Comment: you prob need to upload your rendered html and css to get a answer on this, i dont know the soundcloud script but have you forgotten to set a container width or something?